# How to show only one image in the index page in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have multiple images in my table witch related to `vehicle_id`, like this,

```
image table
id          fileName        vehicle_id
1            1.jpg               1
2            2.jpg               1
3            3.jpg               1
4            4.jpg               1
5            28.png              2
5            28.png              2
6            29.png              2
7            30.png              3
8            31.png              3
9           56.png               3
```

The vehicle table have way to many relationship with the image table and data grap using eager loader in `VehicleController`

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with('image')->get();
        return view('vechicles.index')->withVehicles($vehicles);
```

Now these images are showing in the vehicles/index.blade.php file

```
@foreach($vehicle->images as $image)

     <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{route('vechicles.show',$vehicle->id)}}"><img src="/images/{{ $image->resized_name }}"></a></td>

                </tr>

    @endforeach
```

My problem is occurred now, in this way, I can show all images in the table which related to proper `vehicle_id` but, I need only show one image (to matching `vehicle_id`) like thumbnail to above line. 
Then how can I configure this?

**updated Controller**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $vehicles = Vehicle::with('images')->get();
        return view('vechicles.index')->withVehicles($vehicles);
    }
```

**updated full blade**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
@if($vehicles)

@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
{{$vehicle->district}}
{{$vehicle->town}}
{{$vehicle->brand}}
{{$vehicle->model}}
<hr>
@foreach($vehicle->images as $image)

     <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{route('vechicles.show',$vehicle->id)}}"><img src="/images/{{ $image->resized_name }}"></a></td>

                </tr>

    @endforeach

@endforeach
@endif

</div>

</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through every images right now. You can simply retrieve an image using code below:

```
 $vehicle->images()->first()->resized_name
```

So your code to display image will be:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
 <div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
     @if($vehicles)

     @foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
      {{$vehicle->district}}
      {{$vehicle->town}}
      {{$vehicle->brand}}
      {{$vehicle->model}}
      <hr>
       <tr>
        <td>
         <a href="{{route('vechicles.show',$vehicle->id)}}"><img 
          src="/images/{{ $vehicle->images()->first()->resized_name 
         }}"></a>
        </td>
       </tr>

    @endforeach
    @endif

 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
 @endsection
```

Comment: I need looping because I have print in index other vehicle_id images?

Comment: please see my updated question. I need ont show only one image of table need only one image related to vehicle_id

Comment: just loop through vehicles not vehicle image

Comment: it is displaying first image multiple times

Comment: if it is not working then you need to show me your controller code as well, i need to know what are you passing through your controller to your blade.

Comment: First of all i don't see my updated code in that blade file and also if you show the whole blade file or a little bit more it would be easier for me to get the bigger picture about how you have implemented it.

Comment: Now look at my updated code and paste it in your blade file

Comment: unable to called as **@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)** because I have relashionship between vehicles and images

Comment: If any error shows in the browser the please post it

Comment: yes undefine variable $vehicle in index.blade.php file

Comment: why don't you replace this line in your controller 'return view('vechicles.index')->withVehicles($vehicles);' with this line 'return view('vehicles.index', compact('vehicles'));'

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit along with `with` function like:

```
Vehicle::with(['image' => function($query) {
        return $query->limit(1);
    }])->get();
return view('vechicles.index')->withVehicles($vehicles);
```

And write code to show image as:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href = "{{route('vechicles.show',$vehicle->id)}}"><img src = "/images/{{ $vehicle->images[0]->resized_name }}"></a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: where should I put **Vehicle::with(['image' => function($query) {
        return $query->limit(1);
    }])->get();**

Comment: Answer Updated!

Comment: please see my updated question. I need ont show only one image of table need only one image related to vehicle_id

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take only the first image. But be aware that you must verify if there are any images for that vehicle otherwise an exception will be thrown.

```
@if ($vehicle->images->isNotEmpty())
    <a href="{{route('vechicles.show',$vehicle->id)}}">
        <img src="/images/{{ $vehicle->images->first()->resized_name }}">
    </a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel `first()` function.

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::->where('vehicle_id', 1)->first();
```

Comment: occured this error msg **Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\msoft\Desktop\kakka\resources\views\vechicles\index.blade.php)88

Comment: Update the ans, please check now and try it..!

Comment: please see my updated question. I need ont show only one image of table need only one image related to vehicle_id

Answer (score 0):

You just have to dispaly the first array image in the blade as shown below:

```
 @foreach ($vehicles as $v)
     <img src = "/images/{{ $v->images[0]->resized_name }}"
 @endforeach

 (or) we can also use the laravel first() function to display the first record image from the collection

 @foreach ($vehicles as $v)
     <img src = "/images/{{ $v->images->first()->resized_name }}"
 @endforeach
```